# How to get the amount of torque of a Body in Box2D?

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

I'm making a LibGDX game with Box2D. I have a car, which back wheels get some extra torque when a key is pressed, in order to accelerate. The car is connected with the wheels using joints.

```
public void handleInput(){
    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.D)){
        wheelBody.applyTorque(-100f, true); //Add torque when 'D' is pressed
    }
}
```

But if you press the key when the car is in the air, the torque becomes huge. When the car wheels touch the ground, the car gets launched forward. I could avoid that by using a `MAX_TORQUE` value. The torque will only increase when it's below `MAX_TORQUE`.

But how can I 'measure' the amount of torque currently on the wheels? I haven't found a `wheelBody.getTorque()` function. Or is there another solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you will like the following answer (I don't). I'm not aware of a better way to deal with this than the following suggestions short of modifying the both the C++ Box2D source and the Java source code that interfaces to that.

**Explanation:**

Looking at the Box2D source code, the torque on a body is stored in its `m_torque` member variable. This variable gets incremented by the call to the Java `applyTorque` method. Meanwhile the `m_torque` variable has ***no public way to get its current value***. That came as a surprise to me to discover (i.e. to confirm what it sounds like you already discovered) when initially trying to answer your question.

This variable's only use is in Box2D's island solver code where it's used to increment the body's angular velocity. It's used directly though by the `b2Island` class that's a friend class of the `b2Body` class.

**Work Around #1**

OTOH, calling the world step method, by default invokes the world clear forces method. This in turn resets all bodies' torques back to 0. That means the torque after a given step could be determined from the delta time of that step, the body's rotational inertia, and the body's angular velocity. All of which can be accessed via public methods.

Calculating the torque from the values these value that can be accessed is probably achieved via some math like: `torque = I * w / h` (where `I` is the rotational inertia of the body accessed from the get mass data method, `w` is the angular velocity that's accessed from the get-angular-velocity method, and `h` is the time delta of the step). That assumes that your body has its angular damping set to zero however (which it is by default). This seems pretty ugly to me though, uglier than my second solution at least.

**Work Around #2**

The way I'd deal with the lack of the torque *getter*, is to manually keep track of the sum torque I had applied on the body between world steps and just bite-the-bullet and use that value then.

If you needed, you could track this sum value in the body's user data field if you're not already using that for something else. There's other ways to keep track of it of course but none that are elegant IMO.